# Checkers Game: Not Error Checking Correctly?

Tags: java

I'm making a Checkers game for an assignment. The whole thing is running the way it should, except for one weird thing. Here's my board:

[image: Checkers Board]

I move by giving the source row and column, then the destination row and column.

```
move(int srcR, int srcC, int destR, int destC)
```

I'm supposed to print out an error if I try to move a piece to an invalid spot (not diagonally). So if I try to move a piece from 5 2 -> 4 2, it gives me an error message.

```
if(destR == srcR+1 || destR == srcR-1 &&
    destC == srcC+1 || destC == srcC-1){
        // code code code
}else
    message = "Invalid Move! Can only move diagonally one space.";
```

For most things it works, but if I try to move directly down one space (for example, 2 3 -> 3 3) it's moving the piece and not giving me the error message.

I'm stuck! Any ideas why this may be happening? I can post more code if needed.

Comment: Don't the valid moves depend on which color is moving?

Comment: @ErikPragt that would never validate, as destR cannot be equal to both srcR +/- 1 at the same time.

Comment: desrR can't be == srcR+1 && srcR-1

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: Not really. This game, according the instructions given, doesn't really follow all the rules of real Checkers. Example: When a black piece eats a white piece, it jumps on top of that space rather than going to the next diagonal space past it. Not sure why, but that's what he told us to do.

It should be able to move diagonally any direction, forward or backward.

Comment: @Deactivator2 You're right, of course. I better go home now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your logic, if

```
destC == srcC-1
```

is true, the whole expression will be true. You have to pay attention to the order that Java evaluate the boolean operations~ Add () when necessary~

Answer (score 5):

It is quite simple, I think. There are only four allowed moves.

```
int deltaX = Math.abs(srcR - destR);
int deltaY = Math.abs(srcC - destC);
boolean validMove = deltaX == 1 && deltaY == 1;
```

Of course, this check allows backward moves. But the direction of a backward move depends on the playing color and wether the piece is promoted by reaching the other end.

Comment: +1 It is much clearer to think about it in terms of `dx` and `dy`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks good.  You just forgot to add closing parenthesis around the compound if statement.  So, it's returning true when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Your logical expression is wrong.

have a look at [Java operators precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

If in doubt always use brackets:

```
if((destR == srcR+1 || destR == srcR-1) &&
    (destC == srcC+1 || destC == srcC-1))
```

Comment: Oops! I should have noticed. The additional parentheses fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
if(destR == srcR+1 || destR == srcR-1 && destC == srcC+1 || destC == srcC-1)
```

I think you need some parentheses in here, as this evaluation is tricky since you're trying to compare two expressions at once. Try

```
if((destR == srcR+1 || destR == srcR-1) && (destC == srcC+1 || destC == srcC-1))
```

This way, if (destR = srcR +/- 1) AND (destC = srcC +/- 1), move is valid.

The original way would work out *some* of the time, since Java boolean compares two expressions, or the result of the previous expression and the next one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(destR == srcR+1 || destR == srcR-1 && destC == srcC+1 || destC == srcC-1)
```

is equivalent to

```
if(destR == srcR+1 || (destR == srcR-1 && destC == srcC+1) || destC == srcC-1)
```

In your second example:

```
srcR  = 2
srcC  = 3
destR = 3
destC = 3
```

`destr`(=3) is equal to `srcR`(=2) `+ 1` => `destR == srcR+1` is **true** => the evaluation of `(destR == srcR+1 || (destR == srcR-1 && destC == srcC+1) || destC == srcC-1)` is **true**.

To fix your problem, you need to change your `if` statement to:

```
if((destR == srcR+1 || destR == srcR-1) && (destC == srcC+1 || destC == srcC-1))
```